# how to fetch all GitLab comments of an MR in a Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

IN GitLab MRs we can add comments and we can also add feature to send automated comments in different stages of our Jenkins pipeline.

If I have the MR-ID of a particular MR, and I want to fetch all the MR comments done on that particular MR, then how can I do it in a Jenkins-Groovy environment? Is there are environment variable that can help me in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you would need to use the [GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/).

Considering [Comments on merge requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#comments-on-merge-requests) are done through notes, you would use [List all merge request notes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/notes.html#list-all-merge-request-notes)

```
GET /projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/notes
GET /projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid/notes?sort=asc&order_by=updated_at
```

There are no dedicated environment variables provided by Jenkins, beside the parameters you would pass to your Job, like the project ID and MR ID.

You can see [Groovy examples](https://github.com/search?l=&q=projects%20id%20merge_requests%20id%20notes%20language%3AGroovy&type=code) like this [Jenkinsfile](https://github.com/chrishanditya1/TaperaFrontEnd-master/blob/4ca4e87be5751cc021b118a60da365f2ea7c5811/Jenkinsfile#L181-L212):

```
stage ("Merge Pull Request") {
    // GET PULL REQUEST ID
    sh "curl -H \"PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${approval_token}\" \"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${projectID}/merge_requests\" --output resultMerge.json"
    def jsonMerge = readJSON file: "resultMerge.json"                    
    echo "Request from: ${jsonMerge[0].author.name}"
    // STATUS VALIDATION
    if (jsonMerge[0].state == "opened") {
        // GET ALL COMMENTS ON PULL REQUEST
        sh "curl -H \"PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${approval_token}\" \"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${projectID}/merge_requests/${jsonMerge[0].iid}/notes\" --output comment.json"
        def commentJson = readJSON file: "comment.json"
        def checking = false
        // LOOP ALL COMMENT TO GET APPROVAL
        commentJson.each { res ->
            // CHECK IF CURRENT INDEX HAS SYSTEM FALSE 
            if (!res.system && !checking) {
                // IF COMMENT HAS VALUE: APPROVED AND AUTHOR IS VALID
                if (res.body == "Approved" && approval.contains(res.author.username)) {
                    addGitLabMRComment(comment: "Pull Request Approved by Jenkins")
                    acceptGitLabMR(useMRDescription: true, removeSourceBranch: false)
                } else {
                    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                    error("Sorry, your approval is not valid")
                }
                checking = true
            }
        }
    } else {
        error("Pull Request ${jsonMerge[0].title} ${jsonMerge[0].iid} is already ${jsonMerge[0].state}. Please Create a new Pull Request")
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry @VonC I am new to stackoverflow and did not know that we can accept and upvote an answer. Thanks for sharing the link. I know how to do it in future as well.